# p:dataTable sortBy not working

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable

```
<p:dataTable value="#{externalUsersBean.usersList}" var="user" paginator="true" rows="25">
    <p:column headerText="UID" sortBy="#{user.uid}">
        <h:outputText value="#{user.uid}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Username" sortBy="#{user.username}">
        <h:outputText value="#{user.username}"/>
    </p:column>
    ...
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

I tried changing scope in the bean to ViewScoped, yet not working.
I tried using `sortBy="uid"`  syntax, yet not working.
I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: PrimeFaces showcase works! Find the differences (and check version info)

Comment: Try to add `sortBy="#{user.username}" filterBy="#{user.username}"  filterMatchMode="contains"`

Comment: @YagamiLight not working.

Comment: @Kukeltje sorting is a matter of one adding property, sortBy. there's no more to be added. Thus, I see no differences with my code.

Comment: why filtering should do sth here? filtering is for other thing

Comment: can you post your bean's code too?

Comment: @Apostolos I actually can't. But filtering itself does work properly. I have issues with sorting only.

Comment: tbh, after I filter, modifying does not work properly any more, 'cause if I push the button "modify user", it will give me empty outputtexts

Comment: try to add `Rowkey="#{user.uid}"`

Comment: at your list's getter, do you recreate the list, or do you get the scope-cached one?

Comment: @YagamiLight I  have a table without declaring rowKey as attribute and sorting works.

Comment: @Apostolos i get the scope-cached one.

Comment: OK so what's left is to ask if  table is inside a form.

Comment: @Apostolos yes it is.

Comment: any js errors then?

Comment: not a solution, but you could add a ajax event for sort and see if your listener is actually called just to see that sth is happening actually.